# How to delete duplicate rows in postgres with conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with duplicate rows items but I'd like to delete the rows with specific conditions. eg

```
id   name   car   payment
1    Mary   Kia   True
2    Mary   Kia   None
3    Joe    Honda True
```

How can I delete the second row to be left with

```
id   name   car   payment
1    Mary   Kia   True
3    Joe    Honda True
```

Comment: How do you identify the "bad rows"? `Payment = None` ?

Comment: Can you also add the row (4, Bart, Ford, None) to the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *view* your data this way, then use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, car) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name, car, id;
```

If you really want to do a delete, then use exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND
          t2.car = t1.car   AND
          t2.id < t1.id
);
```

Comment: and if  the id is lower, the user hasn't explain all criteria